# Rate of water level for cone shaped water tank

Tags: calculus, derivatives, word-problem

> A water tank in the form of an inverted cone is being emptied at the rate of $6$ ft$^3$/min. The altitude of the cone is $24$ ft, and the base radius is $12$ ft. Find how fast the water level is lowering when the water is $10$ ft deep.

I am not how to do this problem, but I've tried this using the volume formula for cone:

$$v={1 \over 3} \pi r^3 h\\
{dv \over dm} = {1 \over 3} \pi (12)^2{dh \over dm}\\
6 = {1 \over 3} \pi 144 \cdot{dh \over dm}\\
6 = 48 \pi \cdot {dh \over dm} \\
{1 \over 8 \pi} = {dh \over dm}$$

I am pretty sure that I am wrong.

Could someone help me?

Thanks

The answer is ${6 \over 25 \pi}$ ft /min according to the answer sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take $r=12$ in $$v={1 \over 3} \pi r^2 h\\
{dv \over dm} = {2 \over 3} \pi (12){dh \over dm}$$ because the radius of the water is changing as it drains. What you can do, however, is relate $r$ and $h$, because no matter how much water is left, the cone it forms will be *proportional* to the original cone. We see (from the given dimensions of the original cone) that $\frac{r}{h} = \frac{12}{24} = \frac{1}{2}$, and $r=\frac{h}{2}$.
Let's substitute this for $r$ right away:
$$v={1 \over 3} \pi r^2 h$$
$$v={1 \over 3} \pi (\frac{h}{2})^2 h$$
$$v={1 \over 3} \pi \frac{h^3}{4}$$
$$\frac{dv}{dm} = \pi (r)\frac{h^2}{4}\frac{dh}{dm}$$

$$6 = \pi (\frac{h}{2})^2\frac{dh}{dm}$$
$$6 = \pi (\frac{h^2}{4})\frac{dh}{dm}$$
and plugging in $h=10$:
$$6 =  \pi (\frac{100}{4})\frac{dh}{dm}$$
We get $\frac{dh}{dm} = \frac{6}{25\pi}$.

Comment: I added a few more details. Is there anything I should elaborate on?

Comment: Is it $r= {h \over 2}$ because altitude is 24 and the radius is 12, so ${24 \over 12} = {1 \over 2}$?

Comment: Exactly. Most related rates problems that involve several variables will use a trick like that to put everything in terms of a single variable to get to a solution.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful!

Comment: I just noticed that $v = {1 \over 3} \pi r^3 h$ is not a correct formula for a cone

Comment: @didgocks that's a little hilarious. Let me correct my answer, because I didn't even notice.

Comment: @didgocks I've corrected it. I'm inclined to think that it was just blind luck that my solution produced the right number before, because it contained numerous errors. I hope that didn't cause you any trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Quinn Greicius

Answer (score 0):

Retain symbols till the last plugin step

$$ r = h \cot \alpha \; ; \tan \alpha = \frac12 ;\;  V = \pi r^3/3\; \cot \alpha $$

$$ V =  \pi h^3/3\, \tan ^2\alpha $$

$$ dV/dt = \pi h^2 (dh/dt) \tan ^2\alpha $$

Plug in given values to get  answer tallying with text.